# Contenedor con Keycloak se reinicia constantemente

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tengo corriendo Keycloak en docker, pero luego de iniciar se reinicia una y otra vez.
Para iniciar el contenedor utilizo el comando:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Para el cual tengo preparado el archivo docker-compose.yml con el siguiente contenido:

```
version: '3'
services:  
  keycloak:
    image: imexhs/aplis:keycloak_test_v1
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - keycloak.env
volumes:
  qrs-volume:
  reports-volume:
```

El archivo que pueden ver nombrado keycloak.env, contiene las variables para la conexión a la base de datos, su contenido es:

```
DB_VENDOR=postgres
DB_ADDR=172.17.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=keycloakdb
DB_USER=keycloakuser
DB_PASSWORD=1234
KEYCLOAK_USER=keycloakuser
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=1234
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
```

Para generar una nueva imagen a partir de mis archivos de keycloak, utilicé el comando:

```
docker build -f docker_deploy/dockerfile-keycloak -t aplis:keycloak_test_v1 .
```

Colocando como nombre de la imagen keycloak_test_v1.
Esta imagen luego de usarla en mi servidor de pruebas no funciona, el contenedor aparece reiniciando una y otra vez, con el comando docker ps puedo verlo.

No se qué otra cosa revisar, me parece extraño que no se muestran puertos para este contenedor como se puede ver en la imagen, pero la verdad ya no se que más revisar.